# php include string into isset

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using the cakephp framework I am passing some variables into the url for pagination. I wish to include a string and join a isset

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => array(isset($filterCompany)? $filterCompany : 'all'));
```

what I need is to include 'company:' before the isset

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => array('company:'.isset($filterCompany)? $filterCompany : 'all'));
```

I get an error (unidentified variable $filterCompany) with this, what would be the correct shorthand way?

Comment: Read the error. Post it here if you don't understand it.

Comment: sorry, unidentified variable $filterCompany, but without the 'company' it is fine

Comment: That cannot be your real code (yours triggers `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'`) and `unidentified variable` is obviously not the real error message. Why are some forum regulars so reluctant to provide basic info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => array('company'=> isset($filterCompany)? $filterCompany : 'all')));
```

You were trying to concatenate the result of ternary operator in a improper way.

Comment: have to wait 8mins before I can mark it, but will when i can :-)

Comment: @KiethPower To clarify: This is different from prepending "company:" before $filterCompany. You said: "what I need is to include 'company:' before the isset".

Comment: ahh ok good to know. Although after trying the above I see that this is the correct way for cakephp and it outputs it as company: in the url as desired

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the concatenation is done before the comparison, so you are checking a string into the ternary operator, so you get true and `$filterCompany` is returned.

You can fix is using parenthesis:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => array('company:' . (isset($filterCompany)? $filterCompany : 'all')));
```

Comment: +1 Although this is not the solution for getting the right *url* in CakePHP, this *is* the right explanation of the error message that the OP encountered.